# Minimalmodbus reconnect

Tags: python, arduino, raspberry-pi, minimalmodbus

Working on raspberry with Arduino connected over USB. Communicating over python with minimalmodbus library Trying to make reconnection when Arduino was unplugged for a while.
I tried to repeat the connection code again on error, didn't helped.
Is there any function to reconnect on the serial connection lost?

```
minimalmodbus.baudrate = 9600
instr = minimalmodbus.Instrument('COM5', 1)
instr.serial.baudrate=9600
instr.debug=False
```

Answer (score 1):

You may be facing this problem because you are not closing the COM port. Therefore, you can try first closing that by using below command:

```
instrument.close_port_after_each_call= True
```

Your code should look like this:

```
try:
    minimalmodbus.baudrate = 9600
    instr = minimalmodbus.Instrument('COM5', 1)
    instr.serial.baudrate=9600
    instr.debug=False
    instr.close_port_after_each_call= True 
except:
    print('please check your connection')
```

[More Here](https://minimalmodbus.readthedocs.io/en/stable/apiminimalmodbus.html?highlight=minimalmodbus.MODE_RTU#minimalmodbus.Instrument.close_port_after_each_call)